# Validation message is showing HTML tags

Tags: sitecore-forms

I wanted to use anchor tag in Checkbox so I created a custom checkbox field. The custom checkbox view looks like this

```
<label class="@Model.LabelCssClassSettings.CssClass">
    <input type="checkbox" id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClassSettings.CssClass" @if (Model.Value) { <text> checked="checked" </text> } value="true" data-sc-tracking="@Model.IsTrackingEnabled" data-sc-field-name="extch" data-sc-field-key="exFieldKey"/>@Html.Raw(t => Model.Title)
    <input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" value="false" />
</label>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
```

Now I can add anchor tag in the checkbox. The issue is with the validation. Since this is a required field so the anchor tag with text is showing in the validation as well.

[image: validation]

I dont want to show html tags in validation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try this- `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value).ToHtmlString()))`

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat I am getting 500 error in console and when I checked the error it says "The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. ". As soon as I remove the line @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value).ToHtmlString())), it works fine

Comment: This is the logs : 
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Html.HtmlExtensions.RenderField(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelWrapper`1 model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_FormBuilder_Field_cshtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\publish\Views\FormBuilder\Field.cshtml:line 4

Comment: do you have `system.web` and `system.web.mvc` references in project?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat yes I have these references.